# A short C++ program about the pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main()
    {

        int x[][3]={1,2,3,4,5};
        cout<<&x   <<" "<<*x   <<" "<<x   <<endl;
        cout<<&x[0]<<" "<<*x[0]<<" "<<x[0]<<endl;
        cout<<&x[0][0]<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The result is:

```
0x28fef8 0x28fef8 0x28fef8
0x28fef8 1        0x28fef8
0x28fef8
```

Why `x[0][0]` and x are in the same pointer? What is really in the 0x28fef8? 1 or 0x28fef8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array of arrays like yours look like this in memory

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| x[0][0] | x[0][1] | x[0][2] | x[1][0] | x[1][1] | x[1][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The location of `x`, `x[0]` and `x[0][0]` is all the same.

Also, arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. If you use plain `x` you will get `&x[0]`. If you use `x[0]` you will get `&x[0][0]`. So when you do `*x[0]` it is the same as doing `*&x[0][0]`, and the dereference and address-of operators cancel each other out so you are left with `x[0][0]`, which is the value you print.

Furthermore, to help you understand why `x` is the same as `&x[0]`, you need to know that for any array *or pointer* `x` and index `i` the expressions `x[i]` is the same as `*(x + i)`. That means the expression `&x[i]` is the same as `&*(x + i)`, and since the address-of and dereference operators again cancel each other out `&x[i]` is the same as `(x + i)` (or without the parentheses `x + i`). Now think of the case when `i` is zero, then we have `&x[0]` which is the same as `x + 0` which is the same as `x`. So `&x[0]` is the same as `x`, and vice-versa.

---

For others that wonders what `&x` and `&x[0]` and `&x[0][0]` are representing, please see this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| x[0][0] | x[0][1] | x[0][2] | x[1][0] | x[1][1] | x[1][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
^         ^                   ^         ^
|         |                   |         |
+- &x     +- &x[0][1]         +- &x+1   +- &x[1][1]
|                             |
+- &x[0]                      +- &x[1]
|                             |
+- &x[0][0]                   +- &x[1][0]
```

While all of `x`, `x[0]`, `&x`, `&x[0]` and `&x[0][0]` may represent the same memory address, they are semantically different, i.e they represent different types:

- `x` is a pointer to an array of three `char` (or `char (*)[3]`)
- `x[0]` is a pointer to `char` (or `char *`)
- `&x` is a pointer to an array of arrays of three `char` (or `char (*)[3][3]`)
- `&x[0]` is a pointer to an array of three `char` (or `char (*)[3]`)
- `&x[0][0]` is a pointer to `char` (or `char *`)

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't say that `*x[0]` decays, I say that `x[0]` (notice the lack of dereference operator) decays.

Comment: Oh, *now* I get your point... (A bit thick today). I just never think of `*array` as "decay to pointer, then dereference" but as "exactly equivalent to `array[0]` but with a different syntax".

Comment: Thank you very much.I think I understand. But  what is really in the address 0x28fef8?   1 or 0x28fef8,  you see &x=x=0x28fef8=&x[0][0].

Comment: @Ken Where the compiler places arrays doesn't matter. In your specific case it happened to be at the address `0x28fef8`. The actual address doesn't really matter. And yes, `&x`, `&x[0]` and `&x[0][0]` is the same address, as is `x` and `x[0]`. The different expressions *mean* different things though, even if their values are the same.

Comment: A nitpick. `&x+1` does not evaluate to the same address as `&x[1]`. The numerical value of `&x+1` is `sizeof(x)` offset from `&x`. It points to the block of memory after the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

when array's name meets sizeof() it returns the sizeof the array,when array's name meets &,it returns a pointer to the array,not the address of the array's name.